# Facebook SDK authorization works on phone but not on tablet

Tags: java, android, facebook

currently I am trying to implement the Facebook SDK in my Android app. I followed the official  tutorial and got it working, at least on my Galaxy S2. I can authorize myself and post messages to my wall. But when I try it on my Acer Tablet I get

```
11-19 11:15:54.160: W/System.err(7224): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to reauthorize a session that is not currently open.
11-19 11:15:54.160: W/System.err(7224):     at com.facebook.Session.reauthorize(Session.java:1088)
11-19 11:15:54.160: W/System.err(7224):     at com.facebook.Session.reauthorizeForPublish(Session.java:542)
11-19 11:15:54.160: W/System.err(7224):     at de.lochmann.unnuetze.fakten.FacebookConnect.postToWall(FacebookConnect.java:199)
```

My question might be related to [android facebook sdk - Session: an attempt was made to reauthorize a session that has a pending request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267279/android-facebook-sdk-session-an-attempt-was-made-to-reauthorize-a-session-tha), but as there were no valid answers I thought I'd try again.

The important part of my code :

```
    if (session != null){
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            this.pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.ReauthorizeRequest reauthRequest = new Session.ReauthorizeRequest((Activity) _ctx, PERMISSIONS).setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
            try {
                session.reauthorizeForPublish(reauthRequest);   
            } catch(UnsupportedOperationException uoe) {
                uoe.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this._ctx, "Error,  Reauthorization failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        etc...
    }
```

Do you know what I am missing?
Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go to Settings - Application - Select Your App - Clear Cache - Uninstall and then Install again. Or Also try to logout from the default Facebook app of the Tablet.

Comment: Didn't work, sorry. I reworked some of the code, now it works, still I am not exactly sure why. Now the facebook web login keeps reappearing after authorization if the facebook app isn't installed ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you're trying to call reauthorize when the session is not in the OPEN state. Just checking getPermissions() is not enough to guarantee that the session is open. What you should do is check whether the session is open (via session.isOpen()), and if not, call one of the various open methods first.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/. I had similar issue to yours. I created a base Activity that enbraces the logic to publish to feed and reauthorize if it is needed. Then in activities that needs that funcitonalty, I inherit from this base activity and use the publishing logic. I had the error because I forgot to call super.onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            ....
     }
```

this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to check if the session is opened before so just add:

`if(!session.isOpened()){
     session.reauthorizeForPublish(reauthRequest);

}`

hope my answer will help u .. :)